# SmartSheetAPI using python: createdAt or modifiedAt attributes from a sheet

Tags: python-2.7, smartsheet-api

My Desktop is Debian 8.5 running firefox and running Mozilla Firefox 45.3 and SmartSheet latest version. Lately I have been trying to obtain attributes from a sheet, among them createdAt or modifiedAt, but when I run the code below:

### !/usr/bin/python

import smartsheet

### Token

planilha = smartsheet.Smartsheet(MyToken)

action = planilha.Sheets.list_sheets(include_all=True)
sheets = action.data

### counter

xCount=0

for row in sheets:
    xCount+=1
    print row.id, row.createdAt
print xCount

I get

.......
print row.id, row.createdAt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartsheet/models/sheet.py", line 175, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: createdAt
......

I just wonder why or I certainly miss something in Smartsheet API 2.0 docs..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Any attributes described in the Smartsheet API documentation (which do not specifically appear in a Python code example) represent how the attributes appear in the raw API (JSON) requests/responses. The Python SDK itself actually uses Python variable naming conventions: "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability" (as described here: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). So, for example, the raw API response may contain the attribute "modifiedAt" -- but when using this attribute via the Python SDK, you'll refer to it as "modified_at".

So, try using **created_at** and **modified_at** (instead of **createdAt** and **modifiedAt**).